# App crashes with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent while receiving notification in background

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, android-8.0-oreo

Xamarin forms android application targeting api level 26 crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent`
when receiving notification in background.

From [Notification in oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten), what i understood is only during the app whitelisted duration only the app can make services. How to properly handle this situvation, i call and update my databases when i receive notification, how can i properly manage this.

One answer shows

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
    }
```

But how can i implement this in a xamarin forms application for properly receiving push notifications.

Comment: Do you want to implement the code in Xamarin forms? If so, where do you want to call it? PCl? Android Plarform?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Android 8.0 (API level 26) .

> The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

Read [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) for way around to make work in android Oreo. You can use [Job scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) on notification receive to perform database task .