# Failing foreground service on Oreo

Tags: android, service, widget, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to create a simple widget for Oreo and upwards that reloads its data periodically and upon clicks. The following is the outline code I have:

```
public class WodWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        updateWodWidget(context);
    }

    static void updateWodWidget(Context context) {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    }

    public static class UpdateService extends IntentService {
        private static final String TAG = "WodWidgetUpdateService";
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        public UpdateService() { super(TAG); }
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            String channelId = "foobar";
            String channelName = "Widget update service";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setChannelId(channelId)
                .setContentTitle("notification title")
                .setContentText("notification content")
                .build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            if (Clicks.ACTION_CLICK.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Clicks.handleClickAction(this, mHandler);
            } else {
                getWodData(this);
            }
        }

        protected void getWodData(final Context context) {
            WodData.getInstance().invalidate();
            WodWidget.updateViews(context);

            GetHTMLTask task = new GetHTMLTask(new GetHTMLTask.OnTaskCompleted() {
                @Override
                public void onTaskCompleted() {
                    WodWidget.updateViews(context);
                }
            });
            task.execute(WodData.PARSE_URL);
        }
    }
    static void singleClickHandler(Context context) {
        updateWodWidget(context);
    }

    static void doubleClickHandler(Context context) { [...] }

    private static void updateViews(Context context) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wod_widget);
        WodData wd = WodData.getInstance();

        view    s.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "foobar");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Clicks.ACTION_CLICK, null, context, UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layoutWidget, pendingIntent);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WodWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
    }
}
```

Now this builds and runs fine and for a while, also clicking the widget works. However after a while (some minutes or so), clicking does not refresh the widget anymore and I see the following entry in logcat:

```
W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { act=com.mywidget.action.CLICK flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mywidget/.WodWidget$UpdateService bnds=[56,367][620,1111] } to com.mywidget/.WodWidget$UpdateService from pid=-1 uid=10083 pkg=com.mywidget
```

So I guess it is becoming a background service instead of a foreground service, but why and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654126/3830694

Comment: @KrupalShah I am already using the method advised in the linked topic.