# Floating Window Crash If Called When The App Killed

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-windowmanager

I want to show the floating layout on top of the screen when service Alarm or Call happened. Normally, when the app opens or it is in the background (before swiping it out) it shows and works well. even if I kill the app it still shows (kill = swipe the app)and it is still working. but, if the app is killed and not opened it tries to show (from service of alarm for example) it crashes and I cant even see the crash log in the android studio after terminating the app.
how can I fix that or find the issue?

my code Alarm BroadCast where it called: (the alarm broadcast called as needed)

```
public class BroadcastManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,FloatingWindow.class);
                startService(intent);
}
```

my floating view code :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.greenbook.greenlids.MainActivity;
import com.example.greenbook.greenlids.R;

public class FloatingWindow extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private TextView txt;
    private Button bttn1 , exitBttn;
    private Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


        layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255));


        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

             windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            windowParams.x = 0;
            windowParams.y = 0;
            windowParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        }else{
            windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            windowParams.x = 0;
            windowParams.y = 0;
            windowParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        }

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            layout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_floating_window, null);
        }
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,240,240,255));

        bttn1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.LLbutton);
        exitBttn = layout.findViewById(R.id.exitBttn);
        txt = layout.findViewById(R.id.noteTxt);
        txt.setTextSize(18);
        txt.setText("Natan");
        exitBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeView(layout);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        bttn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean handler = new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        txt.setText("Natan The King");
                    }
                }, 1000*5);
            }
        });

        windowManager.addView(layout,windowParams);


        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private WindowManager.LayoutParams updateParam = windowParams;
            int x , y;
            float touchedX , touchedY;




            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        x = updateParam.x;
                        y = updateParam.y;

                        touchedX = event.getRawX();
                        touchedY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    updateParam.x = (int) (x+event.getRawX() - touchedX);
                    updateParam.y = (int) (y+event.getRawY() - touchedY);

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(layout,updateParam);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

logcat updated:

```
 06-18 11:59:00.263 6722-6722/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
06-18 11:59:00.264 6722-6722/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
06-18 11:59:00.268 6722-6722/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0007, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
06-18 11:59:00.269 6722-6722/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.greenbook.greenlids 
06-18 11:59:00.275 6722-6722/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-18 11:59:00.341 6722-6722/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
06-18 11:59:00.341 6722-6722/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
06-18 11:59:00.422 6722-6722/com.example.greenbook.greenlids I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
06-18 11:59:00.723 6722-6722/com.example.greenbook.greenlids I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-18 11:59:00.750 6722-6722/com.example.greenbook.greenlids D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
06-18 11:59:00.755 6722-6722/com.example.greenbook.greenlids E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.greenbook.greenlids, PID: 6722
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.greenbook.greenlids.models.BroadcastManager: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.greenbook.greenlids/.floating_window.FloatingWindow }: app is in background uid UidRecord{1651455 u0a451 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3399)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1780)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.greenbook.greenlids/.floating_window.FloatingWindow }: app is in background uid UidRecord{1651455 u0a451 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1538)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1484)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
        at com.example.greenbook.greenlids.models.BroadcastManager.onReceive(BroadcastManager.java:40)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1780) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Attach the logcat

Comment: after terminate the app i dont get the logs in android studio stops

Comment: Android studio would'nt have stopped, you will surely get the logs, paste anything which you have in the logcat

Comment: Ashish Kumar , thanks i learned to use the logcat and found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under certain circumstances, a background app is placed on a temporary whitelist for several minutes. While an app is on the whitelist, it can launch services without limitation, and its background services are permitted to run. An app is placed on the whitelist when it handles a task that's visible to the user, such as:

Handling a high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message.
Receiving a broadcast, such as an SMS/MMS message.
Executing a PendingIntent from a notification.
Starting a VpnService before the VPN app promotes itself to the foreground.
taked from the link below
i found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445436/8675712
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654126/8675712