# targetSdkVersion 26 giving exception in crash reports

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

As per the requirement to update targeted SDK version to 26 by November 2018, I tried to update my gradle file a few months ago and released a new version of my app, **after updating both target sdk and compile sdk versions to 26 (from 23)**. Within a day, I started observing crashes in my app on my Firebase console. The reason was I was using TTS service in my app, and when targeting to version 26,  it looks like it required a new implementation for the TTS service, because of the fatal run-time exception. So I reverted the target SDK version to 23 and compile sdk version to 23.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.a.b.c/services.TTSService }: app is in background
```

This exception was seen *only* for the devices on Android OS 8.0 and 8.1.

So a month ago, I bought a new device which is on Android 8.0 (Motorola G6 Plus), hoping to consistently reproduce this error. **But it never happened on this device, even though my app targeting version 26, even when I forcefully triggered the TTS service through my app**. So, I am confused as to how to proceed.

The solution for this exception is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten).

My current code for implementing and calling the TTS service is as follows:

MainActivity oncreate method :

```
 if(!isMyServiceRunning(TTSService.class))//Start a service instance only if service is currently not running
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TTSService.class));
```

TTSService.java:

```
package services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;  
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;

import constants.ConstantParams;

public class TTSService extends Service {

private static TextToSpeech voice =null;

public static TextToSpeech getVoice() {
    return voice;
}

@Nullable
@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // not supporting binding
    return null;
}

public TTSService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try{
            voice = new TextToSpeech(TTSService.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(final int status) {


                }
            });
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("Error in initializing TTS object"));
        FirebaseCrash.log("Error in initializing TTS object");
    }


    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    clearTtsEngine();
    super.onDestroy();

}

public static void clearTtsEngine()
{
    if(voice!=null)
    {
        voice.stop();
        voice.shutdown();
        voice = null;
    }
}

}
```

Do I have to re-implement this feature as per the above mentioned solution? Or can I resort to a simpler approach of targeting the version 26 SDK, but retaining compile SDK version at 23 (it's current state in my app)? Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you starting the service?..show ur code

Comment: for the first time, from MainActivity, after that, it is kept alive in the background, to be called only when necessary. I even made it restart the service on phone-reboot

Comment: Pls show the code

Comment: @al_mukthar Updated in my description

Comment: to whosoever downvoted.. please don't shy away from giving your reason for downvote. This is a really valid scenario for which I feel I have given sufficient detail. In any case anything missing or ambiguous, please let me know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Android 8.0+ doesn't allow background service to be started. Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) for a better understanding of what is the cause of the problem. You can migrate to either [FirebaseJobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) or [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) depending on what is your minSdkVersion. Also, in case you use **androidx** - [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics).

P.S. Note that notification won't work as well after set target SDK to 26.

Answer (score 1):

On android 8(api 26)+ you unable to run services in background. Thing you can do it is to run service in foreground by adding permission service foreground in manifest and by calling `startServiceForeground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
 `startForegroundService()` in place  of `startService()`.
```

Comment: But my service is meant to be in the background, and it should execute even when the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: AFAIK,this is how Android O behaves ...read more here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: this solution would be perfect.. but for the fact that there is now a permanent notification in the notification bar telling me that my app is running.

Answer (score 0):

I Change your service code . check this out 
(follow //ADD THIS comments)

Add follow function to your service

```
//ADD THIS
private IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

//ADD THIS
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) comes to the foreground
    // and binds with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground service
    // when that happens.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        stopForeground(true);
    }
    return mBinder;
}

//ADD THIS
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) returns to the foreground
    // and binds once again with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground
    // service when that happens.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        stopForeground(true);
    }
    super.onRebind(intent);
}
//ADD THIS
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(13, new Notification());
        return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
    }
    return false;
}

//ADD THIS
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public TTSService getServerInstance() {
        return TTSService.this;
    }
}
```

And in your `MainActivity` add this variables upper onCreate()

```
// A reference to the service used to get location updates.
private TTSService mService = null;
// Tracks the bound state of the service.
private boolean mBound = false;

// Monitors the state of the connection to the service.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            TTSService.LocalBinder binder = (TTSService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getServerInstance();
            mBound = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    }
};
```

And add below lines in `onStop()` and `onStart()`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //add for android O
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Unbind from the service. This signals to the service that this activity is no longer
            // in the foreground, and the service can respond by promoting itself to a foreground
            // service.
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    //add for android O
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        bindService(new Intent(this, TTSService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

Hope it's help