# Exception Uknown identifier : Start Service on Oreo Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, exception, android-8.0-oreo

StartService is throwing exception when triggered on Oreo while in previous android was playing fine. So on MainActivity I have

```
play.Click += (sender, args) => SendAudioCommand(StreamingBackgroundService.ActionPlay);
  private void SendAudioCommand(string action)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(action);
        StartService(intent);
    }
```

And when I press play button it throws exception on StartService Command while the intent var is not null. I 've read a lot about JobScheduler but nothing telling about background service as sticky running it from main activity with other way of StartService.

The exception is : Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException:  occurred

Comment: `exception` :Add the exception/stacktrace to your question

Comment: Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred

Comment: this error is related with new limitations added on Andorid O. a `Service` cannot be called in the background and a new way of calling it was introduced but it also requires other changes to be done in the service itself. This thread explain the options you have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50207754/1771254