# Oreo: startService() doesn't throw IllegalStateException when called in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

According to the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) introduced in Android Oreo, calling [startService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startService(android.content.Intent)) when the app is in background should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. Check this question: [Android 8.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten).

I created a sample app targetting Android Oreo that does the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Then I start the app and after press the home button immediately bringing the app to the background state. But the exception is not thrown. How can it be? I expect the app to crash in this case.

Comment: Are you running the app on an Oreo device?

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm running the app on a Pixel 2 with Android 9 (Pie) installed.

Comment: I think there is some timeout (maybe 15s). Try to set that delay to 20000.

Comment: OK, so it should be happening. Can you point to where the docs say it should throw that Exception?

Comment: @egoldx that's a different timeout. This Exception should apparently be thrown as soon as `startService()` is called.

Comment: @TheWanderer https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes, check the section Background execution limits: The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

Comment: Yup, but system still counts that app as foreround.

Comment: @egoldx oh true. That might be why.

Comment: @makovkastar Are you sure your app is in background when `startService` is fired?

Comment: @egoldx I set the timeout first to 20s, then to 30s, still doesn't crash. Yes, I press the home button right after the app has started and wait for 30 seconds.

Comment: Found something interesting. Let me write up an answer.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I need to keep looking.

Comment: I'm puzzled reading the question and comments. I also faced the crash on Oreo. I haven't updated to pie though.

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer unfortunately, but I do have the links for people to trace: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L1549, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java. A diff between `master` and `oreo-release` might help.

Comment: is your app targeting 26 or < SDK?

Comment: @DarShan targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 3):

According to Google's documentation on [background service limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services):

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services.

Generally I've found the window to be something around a minute, but that can certainly be different for others.

Take a look at your overall device logs (run `adb logcat` from the command line or turn off filters in Android Studio's Logcat window) after you've backgrounded the app and look for something like:

> 09-26 13:25:37.150  4741  4756 W ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a267 -1m12s700ms com.example/.MyService

Any request to start a service after that should cause the exception. I'm guessing you'll need to up the timeout to something closer to a minute or two.