# Why startService does not throws an IllegalStateException

Tags: android

I've called startService in background.I run the application and send it to background immediately and I expect to see `IllegalStateException` after 10 seconds in android 8, but it works without any exception. In onCreate of activity:

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class));
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

and in the service:

```
   @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    int i= 0;
    do {
        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: "+ i);
        i++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (i<100);
}
```

gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usergood.test"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Oreo: startService() doesn't throw IllegalStateException when called in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316856/oreo-startservice-doesnt-throw-illegalstateexception-when-called-in-backgrou)

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services.