# Permission Denial: startForeground requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

Lately we have suddenly been seeing a few of the following stack traces. Why could that be? This is from when the app tries to move an audio commentary service into the foreground with a media notification and everything.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: startForeground from pid=1824, uid=10479 requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:5198)
    at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:695)
    at com.example.app.services.AudioService.setUpMediaNotification(AudioService.java:372)
    at com.example.app.services.AudioService.setUpAndStartAudioFeed(AudioService.java:328)
    at com.example.app.services.AudioService.onStartCommand(AudioService.java:228)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.enforcePermission(ActivityManagerService.java:9186)
    at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundInnerLocked(ActiveServices.java:1189)
    at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundLocked(ActiveServices.java:870)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setServiceForeground(ActivityManagerService.java:20434)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:976)
```

Answer (score 506, accepted):

This will happen if you have set `targetSdkVersion = 28` (Android 9 / Pie) or above and have not declared the usage of the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission.

From [the migration notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration#tya) for Android 9:

> Apps wanting to use foreground services must now request the
>   FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission first. This is a normal permission, so
>   the system automatically grants it to the requesting app. Starting a
>   foreground service without the permission throws a SecurityException.

**The solution is to just add the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does that mean if our `targetSdkVersion` is lower than 28, we don't need any permission to run the Foreground services in devices running 28?

Comment: @Volleyball your app won't install on devices running 28 if your targetSdkVersion is lower than 28

Comment: @Sjd They will install just fine. It's not like it's `maxSdkVersion`.

Comment: @Sjd Roy is right, the app will install without any issues, however we won't be able to make use of new things added in API 28.

Comment: Up-voting your answer, but release notes are not an excuse for building non-backward compatible API's. In this case Google could have asked a user to give permission or at least provide a hint instead of crashing app silently. Android becomes very difficult to maintain lately.

Comment: In one app that has sdkVersion 28 and i developed it does not need to this permission and in other app that i developed it need to this permission ,its strang , @RoySolberg

Comment: @miladsalimi If you open AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio you can choose to see the "merged manifest". Maybe there's a dependency that injects that permission usage for you?

Comment: "This is what you get for not reading the release notes properly." There is probably a more polite/friendly way to transport this message.

Comment: @patrickf I agree, but notice how it's myself answering my own question. I was just punishing myself a bit for upgrading the app to Android 9 and not catching this before. :)

Comment: @RoySolberg ah of course I missed that :) Maybe it's time to be a little nicer to yourself, Im sure you are doing fine :)

Comment: They will also RUN just fine on devices under 28 without the changes needed to run on 28 and up. However having the targetSdk at lower than 28 would have have them still run on 28 and up devices.

Google should figure out a system for where it wouldn't need to require specific targets, but the system also has so many hacks that alter app behavior based on target sdk that it's hard for them to go back.

Comment: work for me~ [android compile version 32  target version 32]

Answer (score 52):

> Permission Denial: startForeground requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE

Apps that target Android 9 (API level 28) or higher and use foreground services must request the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission`.

So now we need to add [Foreground service permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#FOREGROUND_SERVICE) in manifest file

- it Allows a regular application to use `Service.startForeground`

**SAMPLE**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

> #### `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app.

[Check this  the migration notes of Android 9 / Pie](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration#tya)

- **Change**

> Foreground service permission

- **Summary**

> Apps wanting to use foreground services must now request the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission first. This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app. Starting a foreground service without the permission throws a SecurityException.

Also Read [**`startForeground()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

- Apps targeting API `Build.VERSION_CODES.P` or later must request the permission `Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` in order to use this API.

Comment: sir i tried ur solution but its not working for me for all android devices.like in Oppo F11 Pro its working but in the Samsung,Nokia and Mi phone app is crashed and got same error in log.can u tell me what i do for fix?

Comment: @Kapilsoni ` got same error in log` what error you are getting

Comment: i got this error "  android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: "

Comment: @Kapilsoni I know it's an old post, but have you tried to reinstall...? Sometimes reinstall fix the issue, like the importance change of the notification channel.

Answer (score 22):

Noting that `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` doesn't require runtime permission requirement. only add below to Manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

the above line should be added before `<application`

Comment: It actually needs to show a notification, therefore needing the notification runtime permission.

Answer (score 15):

For API level 28 or higher, it requires FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission. Otherwise, it can not run and got an exception.

It will be solved by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: i have added but not fixed for me

Comment: @Kapilsoni same issue for me, added but still crashes due to insufficient permission on API 29, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

A `targetSdkVersion` of at least `28` will be mandatory from Nov 1 2019 for app updates in the Play Store. So you'll need to change the target API, and then request the permission `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` to avoid the crash on `startForeground()`