# DRAW OVERLAY doesnt work although permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is granted

Tags: android, permissions

this drives me crazy.... since my Smartphone has API > 23 my youtube overlay doesnt work anymore.... so i implemented all the neccessary stuff.
Now, my app asks for the permission to draw overlays (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) and if i debug my app then i see that the permission is granted. But if i start the overlay i get this error msg:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to create service ...:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@479d57e -- permission denied for window
>   type 2002

Permissions in Manifest are these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

i ask for permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW);
```

i check the permission like this:

```
if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
   permissionShowYoutubeOverlayIsOK = true;
}
```

So, what the hell is wrong here ??

any help is appreciated!!!

bye
phil

Comment: If I remember well, this option should specifically be granted manually by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on Android 8.0 Behavior Changes for apps targeting Android 8.0:

> Apps that use the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission can no longer use the following window types to display alert windows above other apps and system windows:
>
> TYPE_PHONE,
>   TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE,
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR
>
> Instead, apps must use a new window type called TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

So you have to lower TargetSDK or use newer TYPE_xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! that really helped :)
but there have been some more steps to do:

1. change to TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY like you described
2. add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

see:
[Permission Denial: startForeground requires android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382710/permission-denial-startforeground-requires-android-permission-foreground-servic)

3. new notification channel required

   see: [startForeground fail after upgrade to Android 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1)

now it finally runs without issues :)
THANK YOU!!