# android 9 file upload (MultipartUploadRequest) error

Tags: android, file-upload, multipart, cleartext

My project was targeting SDK27 and was working fine and heavily tested. Since google play want to target SDK28, I changed target to SDK28.

After this I started having issue connecting to server in (only) android 9. This turned out to be clearTextTraffic disabled issue as the server doesn't have https (mine is a small app). After adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`in AndroidManifest.xml, this issue was solved and app is again connecting to server as before.

I also have an image upload page using MultipartUploadRequest and this was also failing after SDK28 and this is still not fixed in android 9 (it was definitely working before and is working fine even now in other android versions). So, I am almost sure this is clearTextTraffic and file upload related issue (or at least related with targetSDK change). But not sure what or how to solve this. I am using okhttp. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` is only needed for 29+. So strange story.

Comment: I am getting error only in android 9/SDK29(?) device. Working properly in other devices. clearText default changed to false in SDK28 as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that turned out to be android permission issue with FOREGROUND_SERVICE.

> Apps targeting API Build.VERSION_CODES.P or later must request the permission Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE in order to use this API.

The solution is to add this line

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382710/permission-denial-startforeground-requires-android-permission-foreground-servic)

Also, if anyone else have the issue with clearText error since you don't have an SSL certificate, Let's encrypt is a no profit certificate providing authority that provides free SSL certificate. Check [here](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [here](https://certbot.eff.org/). You can use the software in second link to easily apply and install Let's encrypt SSL certificates in your server. Very easy.