# Start a JobIntentService Implicitly

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

As you know this is how we fire a `JobIntentService`:

```
JobIntentService.enqueueWork(this,
                        MyJobIntentService.class,
                        JOB_ID, 
                        intent);
```

In this approach we *KNOW* which service we want to start and pass its class to the method.
**Here is my question**: *Is there any way to start a service* **implicitly** ?
**Why I need this ?** I'm developing a library that sometimes should start a service that developer extends and obviously I have no access to it from library
**What I tried?** I implemented it with `IntentService` (using intent filters) and worked fine for pre O devices but for Android Oreo I'm receiving this crash log:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start
>   service Intent { act=someAction
>   pkg=somePackage (has extras) }: app is in background uid
>   UidRecord{de24eda u0a238 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

So I moved to `JobIntentService`, now the problem is that I can't start it implicitly.
Any solution or alternative will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution, first query for service you're looking for and check if has the necessary permission for `JobIntentService`, then enqueue work :

```
private final String PERMISSION_BIND_JOB_SERVICE = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE";
Intent handlerIntent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
List<ResolveInfo> result =
        getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(handlerIntent, 0);
            if (result.size() > 0) {
    ResolveInfo info = result.get(0);
    if (info != null && info.serviceInfo != null &&
            info.serviceInfo.permission != null){
        String permission = info.serviceInfo.permission;
        if (permission.equals(PERMISSION_BIND_JOB_SERVICE)) {
            try {
                Class<?> serviceClass = Class.forName(info.serviceInfo.name);
                JobIntentService.enqueueWork(this,
                        serviceClass,
                        JOB_ID, handlerIntent);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                //Handle exception if you will
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in app module manifest I added `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE` to my service as well:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MY_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Sorry for asking what may be a silly question but how does this work exactly?  Can this be done without using intents and intent-filters? If I have multiple functions in the intent service that do different things based on data I pass in the intent, how do I then implement that?

Comment: You can use Bundle object to put your commands an its arguments to define the functionality you need to be done.