# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException When starting service from foreground Activity

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I start a service from a foreground activity with the following way:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.SyncService"));
    ComponentName c = ctx.startService(i);
```

But i get this exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { ... }: app is in background uid NULL

I call the startService from my app which is in the foreground, so restrictions [Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) dont apply here.

**HOWEVER**

If i start manually the other app which holds the service and put it on the background, and then from my app call the service, works fine. But only if the other app is running in the background.

Comment: The restriction is on the app that has the Service, not the app that's starting the Service.

Comment: Please add complete logcat

Comment: The background restriction. Unless you use `startForegroundService()` the app that has the Service has to currently be in the foreground, not the app that's calling `startService()`.

Comment: I've already told you twice.

Comment: @TheWanderer Okay, but why when i start the app that has the service and then i reopen my app (service app goes to background) to call that service works fine? The service app is still in background.

Comment: It's not. You have an Activity running. Leave the Activity in Recents for a while and it'll move to the background state.

Comment: @TheWanderer Iam confused. When you press the home button an app/activity goes to background right?

Comment: Not immediately. There's a difference between the visual background and the process background.

Comment: @TheWanderer okay thankss. Is there a link to read about visual background and the process background?

Comment: The same question is being answered here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten)