# Old version of firebase bug?

Tags: android, firebase

**Not allowed to start service Intent `{ act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService (has extras) }:` app is in background uid UidRecord

`com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver.doStartService`**

This bug seems to be a limitation on the background startup service after **Android 8.0**. I checked my own code and did not directly call `context.startService()`. The log looks like the error caused by firebase. The firebase version I am using is `11.4.2`, View source code in the `AppMeasurementReceiver.class` has a direct call to `context.startService ()`, but this part of the latest version of the code has not been modified to `context.startForegroundService ()`, so a little confused, did not practice the steps of recurring Some people know how to solve it?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654126/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar If there is a problem with my own startup service, it will definitely crash every time, but it is not