# Notifications are not working when the app is closed

Tags: android, notifications

I try to use notifications, but I got into trouble on Android 8.
Everything works fine when the software is in run mode.But when I close it, it crashes after a while:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=ACTION_START cmp=com.neuron.food/neurons.com.food.food.Notification.NotificationIntentService_Message (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{3aaf797 u0a132 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten)

Comment: share your code

Comment: It seems you are trying to start a service from notification action. Please attach the code of notification and service.