# Android 9.0 (APi 28): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, android-service, android-9.0-pie

I'm building a music app, everything is alright but recently, app will be crashed. When see my crash list on fabric so notice that only happens on os 9.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>       Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.store/android.store.MusicPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=android.store.mediaservice.PLAY_PLAYLIST cmp=android.store/.mediaservice.MediaService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{1aba0fa u0a192 SVC bg:+5m42s914ms idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

I couldn't reproduce that issue because it rarely happen.
These following code cause crash :

```java
if (intent.hasExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_INDEX)) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaService.class);
    i.setAction(MediaService.ACTION_PLAY_PLAYLIST);             i.putExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_INDEX, intent.getIntExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_INDEX, 0));
    i.putExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_TRACK_IDLIST, intent.getStringArrayExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_TRACK_IDLIST));     startService(i);
} else if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRAS_SHUFFLE)) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaService.class);
    i.setAction(MediaService.ACTION_PLAY_SHUFFLE);
    i.putExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_TRACK_IDLIST, intent.getStringArrayExtra(MediaService.EXTRAS_TRACK_IDLIST));
    startService(i);
}
```

So what's the main reason cause crash and solution for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Comment: @Le Minh , android O and above does not allow to run service in background .
You need to use startForegroundService(i) instead of StartService(i) and attach a notification to the foreground service

Comment: so why that issue is occur on android Pie not android O ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For pre Oreo devices, you have to use `startService()`, but from Oreo onwards devices, you have to use `startForgroundService()`. Check the below sample code.

```
   ContextCompat.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

[Background Execution Limits in Android Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background). ContextCompat makes Build.Version check inside and calls right method

To show the notification to the user use below code in your service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,new Notification());
}
```

Comment: context.startForegroundService is not the solution .i don't know why it got vote ???

Comment: ForegroundService is used for long running processes that users have to know about them. like music player or download manager and etc.

Comment: @Mr.AF I think ,illegalstateException is caused due to trying to start the service when app is in background in android O and above device .Correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: @Mr.AF If context.startForegroundService is not the solution then Can you explain me what is the best solution for this exception ?

Comment: The solution is IntentService ,@Ashishsingh and @sm_

Comment: @Mr.AF So How r u starting an IntentService ?

Comment: Service.enqueueWork ... on so on. the solution is much more complicated that just starting a foreground service.