# What is the best/correct way to play/stop a ringtone on Android 8+ even when the app is in the background?

Tags: android, background, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler, ringtone

First some background info

I had a problem with starting a background service when the app is in the background in Android 8+.
The documentation clearly describes [the new limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) for backgroud execution.

So I went ahead and implemented my service as a *JobIntentService* (the recommended way for simple cases).
This seems to work well...for the first error I got anyway.

### Playing a ringtone...should be easy

Before Android 8, our app was using a background service to play a ringtone using *RingtoneManager* (starting playback in *onStartCommand()* and stopping when the service is stopped). This worked pretty well.

Because of the new background execution limits, I tried to use the *JobIntentService* for this task as well but noticed it can't be explicitly stopped. OK, so I tried with *JobScheduler* and a *JobService* (since as I understand it *JobIntentService* should basically do the same thing without the hassle of creating the *JobInfo*). I don't have any special requirements, so I went with the same stuff used by *JobIntentService* (*setOverrideDeadline(0)*).

The *JobService* is started, but it's immediately stopped by the system even when I return *true* from *onStartJob()*. I'm looking into this - maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

### ...or is it?

- I also considered a *bound service*, but it seems weird since I also need to call it from another service (but maybe this would be OK). Bound services are not influenced by the background limitations so maybe this would be the right way.
- A regular *background service* worked fine before Android 8, but I obviously can't use that.
- I don't think a *foreground service* is the way to go for simple ringtones.
- I even played with the idea of trying to raise the app to the foreground to go around the problem, but from googling around, this feels more like a hack than a proper solution.

### This should be simple right?

I'm a little perplexed by the fact that the simple matter of playing and stopping a ringtone doesn't seem to be dead simple including the background stuff (if I have an app with some kind of calling capability, I just need this to work, so why should I need to mess with this and reinvent the wheel here?).

I'm not primarily an Android developer, so I might be missing some important obvious things. I tried googling this to no end and I got tons of examples of how to play stuff using *RingtoneManager* and even *MediaPlayer* or some such, but I didn't see any mention of the background problem.

Any input is appreciated, thanx.

Comment: Why you can't use a regular Background Thread on Android 8? The only "restriction" is that you should have to place a notification icon in the statusbar while the BackgroundService is running....so it's not that bad. However you can lower the notification priority to "MIN" and it will be quite-hidden in most of Android implementation (in most of them you have to drop-down the statusbar to show the running service notification because no any icon is showed in other situations)

Comment: The notification "restriction" applies to foreground rather than background services. Background services can be used even in Android 8, but not when the app itself is running in the background (as in "press home button, app disappears and you see the home screen"). There is an exception to that where under some circumstances your background service gets white-listed and is allowed to run even when the app is in the background.

Comment: I'm intensively using Background Services in many of mine Apps and I don't understand your phrase about "foregound vs background"...My App is always non-running or just sent in background without any difference in the BackgroundService behaviour which is still running without bothering about anything.

Comment: As I mentioned in the first paragraph - this is a change in Android 8 (see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html). This leads to the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Comment: I'm targetting SDK 28 (Android 9) in most of my Apps in which I'm using BackgroundServices without any problem. I started to develope one App on 2014 and I updated it until few months ago, so I've passed through all Android changes about Permissions, Security and other things. I just start an IntentService (which has its own Thread) and place an icon in the statusbar for the whole Thread-lifecycle. The Service remains active until the App is explicitely terminated by Android Settings --> Apps interface page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a foreground service to play the ringtone. I can still stop the service and the service is allowed to start from the background.

The stock android phone app also shows a notification for a call so maybe they do the same thing here.