# Android error when updating user's location in the background

Tags: java, android

> `STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {LocationService.SmartGeolocation }: app is in background`

I met this error when developing an app that updates user's location every second and draws a path for the user as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten)