# Android JobIntentService as wrapper on another service

Tags: android, jobintentservice

This one will require a bit of context, please bare with me...

---

I have migrated a dependency for evaluating NFC data to a new application. Whenever an NFC tag is discovered, my application will spawn an Activity to handle the event. In the `onCreate` function of this `NfcActivity`, a background service (let's call it `MyNfcHelperService`) is started to retrieve some data on the scanned tag:

```
class NfcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /*...*/
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        /*...*/

        val intent = Intent(this, MyNfcHelperService::class.java)
            .putExtra(/*...*/)
        
        startService(intent)
    }
}
```

The work produced by this service is later retrieved and used by the `NfcActivity`. It all used to work just fine, but once released into the wild we noticed some crashes, which would report `Not allowed to start service Intent` on the `startService(intent)` call.

I quickly came across [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten), suggesting this is due to some improvements in RAM management on background processes (introduced in Android 8).

Following the accepted answer and comments raised, I studied the [docs on JobIntentServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) and ended up with a similar setup. I would've liked to drop the `MyNfcHelperService` all together and move its logic into the `MyJobIntentService`. **But what happens inside `MyNfcHelperService` is an absolute black-box to me.** Thus, I wrapped the aforementioned service inside the `onHandleWork` of my derived `JobIntentService` like so:

```
class MyJobIntentService: JobIntentService() {

    companion object {
        private const val JOB_ID = 1000

        fun start(context: Context) {
            val intentPkm = Intent(context, MyNfcHelperService::class.java)
                .putExtra(/*...*/)
            enqueueWork(context, intentPkm)
        }

        private fun enqueueWork(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService::class.java, JOB_ID, intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        applicationContext.startService(intent)
    }
}
```

Then I applied this class in `NfcActivity`:

```
class NfcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /*...*/
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        /*...*/

        MyJobIntentService.start(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Thus far, the code seems to work. But I am hesitant to release it into the wild, because it feels a bit hacky and I am unsure if this solution actually solved the aforementioned issue. After all, I understand that this infrastructure creates a background service from a scheduled job.

---

So, is my code robust towards the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent` error, or did I totally head the wrong way? If the latter is the case, can anyone suggest an alternate approach, taking into account that I cannot access the guts of `MyNfcHelperService`?

Comment: Why Jobintentservice? Use work manager

Comment: @MD interesting, [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) seems to use JobScheduler for API 23+ under the hood as well. So I guess my question remains, can I use this approach, while maintaining the ```MyNfcHelperService```?

Comment: I guess WorkManager is more stable now days. Your approach is right but it will not work in some manufacturer devices like I saw this type of crashs in Honor (Huwai) devices

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll look into it and update my post as new insights come along.

Answer (score 0):

After @MD's comment, I changed my approach towards using WorkManager. This should be most robust against different API versions. I followed the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) and arrived at the following worker setup:

```
class MyNfcHelperServiceWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val intent = Intent(context, MyNfcHelperService::class.java)
                .putExtra(/*...*/)

        context.startService(intent)

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Then I adjusted the code inside `NfcActivity` like so:

```
class NfcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /*...*/
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        /*...*/

        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyNfcHelperServiceWorker>()
            .build()
            .also { helperServiceWorkRequest ->
                WorkManager.getInstance(this)
                    .enqueue(helperServiceWorkRequest)
            }
    }
}
```

Initial tests have worked just fine. My understanding of why this fixes the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent` issue would be that android will now schedule a work request which meets the requirements of **launching `MyNfcHelperService` only when my app is allowed to create background processes**.

That said, I still have a bit of a headache using a worker to start a service. Feels really redundant to do so and I am unsure of any additional implications this may lead. Thus, I wont accept this as an answer just now.

I'd really appreciate any additional comments and/or answers on the matter!