# IllegalStateException on Samsung only

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Ive been recently getting a lot of errors in the android console for Samsung devices that i cant emulate

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4120)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:272)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2066)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8016)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1688)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1633)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:683)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:683)
  at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:99)
  at com.area52.techno.helpers.MediaButtonIntentReceiver.startService (MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java:107)
  at com.area52.techno.helpers.MediaButtonIntentReceiver.onReceive (MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java:143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4111)
```

No other devices have this issue

```
Galaxy S9 (starqltesq)  98  24.2%
Galaxy S10 (beyond1)    76  18.8%
Galaxy S10e (beyond0)   58  14.3%
Galaxy A70 (a70q)   41  10.1%
Galaxy S8+ (dream2lte)  27  6.7%
Galaxy A50 (a50)    23  5.7%
Galaxy S10+ (beyond2)   16  4.0%
Galaxy S9 (starlte) 16  4.0%
Galaxy S20 5G (x1q) 16  4.0%
Galaxy S10+ (beyond2q)  15  3.7%
Galaxy S10e (beyond0q)  7   1.7%
Galaxy A8(2018) (jackpotlte)    5   1.2%
Galaxy A6 (a6lte)   4   1.0%
Galaxy A40 (a40)    3   0.7%
```

Can anyone tell me whats different about the Samsung device that may cause this?

Edit :

Class thats causing issue it seems

```
private static void startService(Context context, String command) {
        final Intent i = new Intent(context, MusicService.class);
104        i.setAction(MusicService.SERVICECMD);
105        i.putExtra(MusicService.CMDNAME, command);
106        i.putExtra(MusicService.FROM_MEDIA_BUTTON, true);
107        startWakefulService(context, i);
    }
```

Comment: and the error occurs at any time? or the error occurs when x action is executed?

Comment: On launch people are saying.Then. it shuts down.

Comment: maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/

Comment: in this line of code, what is there? `MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java:107`, although it may be related to what @Hooman says

Comment: That other question is very relevant. give me a minute and i will post the code asked for

Comment: Ive edited post. thanks.