# How to get device id or imei number in android 10 or above

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app i am trying to get user imei number to prevent any fraud activity from user, so user can not register multiple fake accounts.

My app is working fine with my old device android version 7.0, But in my new device android version 10 app immediately crash on splash screen where i am trying to get imei number.

When i try to track run log i got this:

```
The user 10335 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers
```

**Run (Run Log):**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgkmJBuHi8GCNgJFHCltXaAnFizaUsGy/view?usp=sharing

i try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />` in manifest.xml but still not work

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

this is the main (splash) screen where my app is crash:

```
package com.xitij.spintoearn.Activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkAds;
import com.gun0912.tedpermission.PermissionListener;
import com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermission;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Models.Settings;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Models.User;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.R;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Util.Constant;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Util.Ex;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Util.Method;
import com.xitij.spintoearn.Util.RestAPI;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private Constant constant;


    private String GetDeviceID(){
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceID = null;
        int readIMEI= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if(deviceID == null) {
            if (readIMEI == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                deviceID = tm.getDeviceId().toString();
            }
        }
        return deviceID;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                Constant.DeviceID = GetDeviceID();
                login(Constant.DeviceID);
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
                finish();
            }


        };

        TedPermission.with(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

                .check();


        constant = new Constant(Splash.this);
        Constant.DeviceID = GetDeviceID();
        Ex.getIPaddress();
        if(Ex.isConnectionEnable(this) && Ex.checkAndRequestPermissions(this,this)){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                       //login(Constant.DeviceID);
                }
            },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }
    public void login(final String deviceid) {
        String login = RestAPI.API_Device_Login + "&deviceid=" + deviceid;
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(login, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                Log.d("Response", new String(responseBody));
                String res = new String(responseBody);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constant.AppSid);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String success = object.getString("success");

                        if (success.equals("1")) {
                            String user_id = object.getString("user_id");
                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            String sendEmail = object.getString("email");
                            String userPhone = object.getString("phone");
                            String userCode = object.getString("user_code");
                            constant.sharedEditor.putBoolean(constant.isLogin, true);
                            constant.sharedEditor.putString(constant.profileId, user_id);
                            constant.sharedEditor.putString(constant.userName, name);
                            constant.sharedEditor.putString(constant.userEmail, sendEmail);
                            constant.sharedEditor.putString(constant.userPhone, userPhone);
                            constant.sharedEditor.putString(constant.userCode, userCode);
                            constant.sharedEditor.commit();
                            LoadSettings();
                            Constant.user =new User("00",name,sendEmail,"000",userPhone,userCode);
                            Method.UserLoginLogs(user_id,"Login",Constant.DeviceID);
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            Intent inst = new Intent(Splash.this, Login.class);
                            inst.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(inst);
                            finish();
                            // Ex.okAlertBox(getResources().getString(R.string.login_failed_message));
                            //Toast.makeText(Login.this, getResources().getString(R.string.login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Server Maintenance");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("System is Undergoing Maintenance. Please try again later.");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.ok_message),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
      });
    }
    public void LoadSettings() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(RestAPI.API_Settings, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                Log.d("Response-ls", new String(responseBody));
                String res = new String(responseBody);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constant.AppSid);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String app_name = object.getString("app_name");
                        String app_logo = object.getString("app_logo");
                        String app_version = object.getString("app_version");
                        String app_author = object.getString("app_author");
                        String app_contact = object.getString("app_contact");
                        String app_email = object.getString("app_email");
                        String app_website = object.getString("app_website");
                        String app_description = object.getString("app_description");
                        String app_developed_by = object.getString("app_developed_by");
                        String app_faq = object.getString("app_faq");
                        String app_privacy_policy = object.getString("app_privacy_policy");
                        String publisher_id = object.getString("publisher_id");
                        boolean interstital_ad = Boolean.parseBoolean(object.getString("interstital_ad"));
                        String interstital_ad_id = object.getString("interstital_ad_id");
                        String interstital_ad_click = object.getString("interstital_ad_click");
                        boolean banner_ad = Boolean.parseBoolean(object.getString("banner_ad"));
                        String banner_ad_id = object.getString("banner_ad_id");
                        boolean rewarded_video_ads = Boolean.parseBoolean(object.getString("rewarded_video_ads"));
                        String rewarded_video_ads_id = object.getString("rewarded_video_ads_id");
                        String redeem_currency = object.getString("redeem_currency");
                        String redeem_points = object.getString("redeem_points");
                        String redeem_money = object.getString("redeem_money");
                        String minimum_redeem_points = object.getString("minimum_redeem_points");
                        String payment_method1 = object.getString("payment_method1");
                        String payment_method2 = object.getString("payment_method2");
                        String payment_method3 = object.getString("payment_method3");
                        String payment_method4 = object.getString("payment_method4");
                        String daily_spin_limit = object.getString("daily_spin_limit");
                        String ads_frequency_limit= object.getString("ads_frequency_limit");
                        String video_add_point= object.getString("video_add_point");
                        String app_refer_reward= object.getString("app_refer_reward");
                        String registration_reward= object.getString("registration_reward");
                        String video_ads_limit= object.getString("daily_rewarded_video_ads_limits");

                        Constant.settings = new Settings(app_name, app_logo, app_version, app_author, app_contact, app_email, app_website, app_description, app_developed_by,
                                app_faq, app_privacy_policy, publisher_id, interstital_ad_id, interstital_ad_click, banner_ad_id, rewarded_video_ads_id, redeem_currency, redeem_points,
                                redeem_money, minimum_redeem_points, payment_method1, payment_method2, payment_method3, payment_method4, interstital_ad, banner_ad, rewarded_video_ads,daily_spin_limit,ads_frequency_limit,video_add_point,app_refer_reward,registration_reward,video_ads_limit);
                        Log.d("Response-ls",ads_frequency_limit );
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for a bit and I don't think it possible anymore without having system app permissions.

If you just need a unique identifier for a device, AndroidID may be sufficient:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID

Or you could link directly to the setting page with [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS) intent, and instruct the user to manually get the IMEI:

Comment: can u please help me with code (Android ID)

help me to edit my code