# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver (exception showed up in Google play store internal testing)

Tags: flutter, google-play

I deployed my flutter app to Google play store internal testing and after one hour, I saw this exception in the Pre-launch report details.  I am not even sure where to start debugging.  Could Someone please help? I don't have a lot of knowledge of Android since I am using Flutter.

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
> com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
> act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE
> cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService
> }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2a75503 u0a192 TRNB
> bg:+2m53s648ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4035)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
> (ActivityThread.java:1924)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:106)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:592)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:947) Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not
> allowed to start service Intent {
> act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE
> cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService
> }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2a75503 u0a192 TRNB
> bg:+2m53s648ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}   at
> android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1715)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1670)   at
> android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:720)
> at alj.a (alj.java:2)   at alm.a (alm.java:3)   at wnv.a (wnv.java:2)
> at
> com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.onReceive
> (PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.java:6)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4026)

I also managed to download the full logcat which is very large file. I am not sure how to include the file over here.

Comment: I just received the same error from the Google Play Console for an app I wrote using Jetpack Compose. I don't know how much help it will be but if you click show more on the page with the error, it shows the devices it failed on. In my case, it's a Google Pixel 5 running Android 11 (SDK 30). I am now installing an emulator to test on that device.
The "see more" is on the top-right above the error message. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yNbd.png)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  When I clicked on show more, I was able to get the full exception.  I updated the post with the complete exception I am getting.  The ex exception is Detected on google Pixel 5.

Comment: I just broke in Play Console testing on the same.
I'm crashing on Pixel 5 and Pixel 6 phones, Android 11 and 12. This is a fairly new one, my bundles were testing fine until my latest bundle drops.

Comment: I'm going to re-submit an old-old bundle  that previously passed and see if it breaks.  Yay for git!

Comment: Update.  A release that previously passed now suffers the same issue as my latest.  I believe I updated to a newer flutter/dart quite recently.  This points to a possible infrastructure issue (i.e. something in my build environment has changed since this code previously survived whatever ungodly torture they put it through)

Comment: Are we sure this is not an issue on Google Play's side? I just got the same errors today, though the message in the inbox said 'No issues found'. And then I was able to just submit the release for review (haven't got the result of the review yet).

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this is a robo test issue, having seen reports of similar in the past.  I'm going to ignore it for a day or two, polish my code, maybe set up a clean docker flutter environment in the mean time :)

Comment: Same error in Pre-launch report on Google Pixel 5 (SDK 30) & Google Pixel 6 (SDK 31) I try some devices on firebase Test Lab (API Level 23,24,28,30,31). All passed without errors. It seems that this error only happens with Google Pixel.

Comment: Same error here BUT it happens that I do own a Google Pixel 7. Use it to test it from Android Studio and I got no error. I only got them in Playstore.
Also note this is a new app version, previous one worked without problems. However I did added a capacitor plugin that is performing native firebase plugin with social-media accounts.

Comment: There is also a video in crash details showing the testing steps. For me the crash happens after they click the "Install" button in Google AdMob rewarded ads, it shows a Google Play "Terms of Services" popup dialog, almost looks like they never used Play Store on that testing device. When I test locally, clicking the "Install" button correctly opens the app detail page in Play Store.

Comment: Yea, so my submission got through and the app was approved and released to the store. Despite the errors in the report.

Comment: Commenting for the records. Got the same issue with a new app built with Flutter, but not luck reproducing it on a physical device.

Comment: Vaguely related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Comment: @MariusBughiu how did you argue with Google let your submission got through ?

Comment: There was no arguing. I just clicked submit and got no feedback, the app was simply published ~24h later.

Comment: My submission got through and the app was approved for closed testing. I did not do anything from my side.

Answer (score 1):

> `flutter downgrade` to as much as possible

> You have to `uninstall` and `reinstall` the app, and also have to `clear the data and cache` from the Settings page.

Try it.
I have solved the problem this way.